# DateTime error type mismatch

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to insert date and time to my access db using c#, this is what i currently have, but it says mismatch

```
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection();
myConn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Copro-3\Employee.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

myConn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = myConn;

cmd.CommandText = @"insert into EmployeeTimeIn (FirstName,LastName, TimeIn) values ('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"' , ?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TimeIn", DateTime.Now);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Success");
myConn.Close();
```

I'm trying to insert date and time to my access db using c#, this is what i currently have, but it says "data type mismatch"

Comment: What are the types of `FirstName`, `LastName` and `TimeIn` columns? And parameterize your first two value as you did for the last one. Also would be better to use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command.

Comment: first and last name both text type. TimeIn is Data/Time in my db.

Comment: `Data/Type`? You mean `Date/Type`? Or `DBDate`?

Comment: Date/Time. my apologies.

Comment: OLE DB doesn't have a type as `Date/Time` or `DateTime`. Can you please _exactly_ say what are your column types?

Answer (score 0):

Type of TimeIn in ms access table is different than you pass TimeIn value as parameter